# Проблема со скроллингом текста в консоли

Tags: python, ubuntu, консоль

У меня есть питоновский скрипт, который выступает в роли сервера(`baseHTTPserver`). Я его запускаю в консоли приходит вывод, но проскроллить (если ее поступило много) я не могу, появляются такие символы `^[[A^ ^[[A^ ^[[A^ ^[[A^` и т.п, но если просто потянуть за уголок консоли, будет виден вывод, который чуть выше. Почему не скроллит?

Comment: для скроллинга вверх попробуйте Shift+PgUp

Comment: Попробуйте перед запуском скрипта написать в консоле ``bash`` и нажать enter. Вероятнее всего у вас стоит ``sh``.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Вариант 1**: Вероятнее всего, у вас стоит оболочка `sh`, в которой скроллинг (по крайней мере у меня) не работает. Но если сменить на `bash`, то скроллинг работает адекватно, и не выводит `^[[A^[[A^[[A^`:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но если сменить оболочку на `sh`, то появляются проблемы со скроллингом:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]